# Railties installed but throws error on port binding with rails s -b

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm attempting to access a locally hosted rails app via my smartphone, and wanted to bind my rails server to a new port using

```
rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 80
```

However, when I do, the following error is thrown:

> /Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0.a) among 16 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)

I am using rvm at the moment, and running `` ls `rvm gemdir` gems `` gives me:

```
...
rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.3
rails4-autocomplete-1.1.1
railties-4.2.6
rake-11.2.2
rdoc-4.2.2
...
```

I'm puzzled as to why railties is found for all the other dependent things in my gemset, except in this one case.

Comment: `rails s` works without any error?

Comment: Yes, it will work on with the default port (3000) with no problems.

Comment: for me this command gives error `'bind': Permission denied - bind(2) for 0.0.0.0:80 (Errno::EACCES)`. it works only with `sudo`. what would be if you run it with `sudo`?